# Is $ \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})$ absolutely convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})$ is convergent. Is it absolutely convergent? If so prove it if not then find a rearrangement where the series sums to a number greater than $1$.

Theorem: Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is monotonically decreasing and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=0$ then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}a_k$ converges.

My attempt: First note that $\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}=(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})(\frac{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}$. Then $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}=\frac{1}{\infty}=0$.

Now let $s_k=\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}$, so $s_{k+1}=\sqrt{k+2}-\sqrt{k+1}$. Then $$s_{k+1}-s_k=\sqrt{k+2}-\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}$$ $$=\sqrt{k+2}-2\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}$$
$$<(k+2)-4(k+1)+k$$
$$=-2k-2<0$$
Thus, $\{s_k\}$ is monotonically decreasing, so by the theorem, $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})$ converges.

Now for absolutely convergence, we have to check if $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty |(-1)^{k+1}(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})|$ converges. Notice that $$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty |(-1)^{k+1}(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})|=\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty (\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})$$.

Since this diverges, it is not absolutely convergent. The part that I am stuck on is the rearrangement part. Could I get a hint on how to rearrange the series to get a number greater than 1? Thanks.

Comment: The divergence is straightforward. Notice that it is a telescopic sum. Thus $\displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^n (\sqrt{k+1}- \sqrt{k}) = \sqrt{n +1} - 1$. Take the limit $n \to \infty$ to complete the proof.

Comment: $\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}$ is decreasing, so by the alternating series test, the original sum converges.

Comment: @Houston. It should even converge to $1+2\left(2 \sqrt{2}-1\right) \zeta \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)$

Comment: Why not to use $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k+1}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}}$ ?

Comment: The fact that $k\mapsto\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}$ is decreasing is obvious from the already noticed $\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}=1/(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k})$; no dedicated derivation needed.

Comment: I forgot 1 more criteria for the alternating series test to work, and that is that each term tends to 0, but no biggie since that is the case here